# installing cuda toolkit 6.5 on ubuntu 19.1

Tags: nvidia, 19.10, cuda

I have an NVIDIA Quadro FX 5800 GPU and want to use it for GPU programming. My current operating system is ubuntu 19.10. I could install "Driver Version: 340.107" from ubuntu additional drivers and now nvidia-smi runs okay.

Based on the searches that I did, I found that to install nvcc I need to install Cuda toolkit which the latest compatible with my graphic card version is Cuda toolkit 6.5. I could download this version from the NVIDIA website but I cannot install it due to its dependencies. For example, it needs gcc 4.8 which is too old. Does anybody have an idea how can I do GPU programming with this old graphic card on my relatively new Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 1):

It took me several days and trying different methods including a docker image (which didn't work) to figure out how can I solve it:

1. install the latest compatible driver from ubuntu->software & update->Additional Drivers-> Using NVIDIA binary driver (for my case the latest compatible was 340.107). Make sure nvidia-smi works successfully.
2. install gcc-4.7 and g++-4.7 by adding the following lines to /etc/apt/sources.list and then running sudo apt update && sudo apt install g++-4.7 gcc-4.7

   `deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
   deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe`

   the above lines coud be removed from /etc/apt/sources.list after that
3. if you have previously installed a newer version of gcc and g++, remove gcc and g++ which are symbolic links from your $PATH and create new sybolic links to newly installed gcc-4.7 and g++-4.7 (e.g sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 /usr/bin/gcc)
4. install required libraries by: apt-get install libglu1-mesa libxi-dev libxmu-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
5. Download [cuda_6.5.14_linux_64.run](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-65) from NVIDIA website and extract it by: ./cuda_6.5.14_linux_64.run --tar mxvf
6. copy InstallUtils.pm file from the extracted package and copy it to your perl-base location (for mine it was /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base)
7. set your perl library path (e.g export PERL5LIB=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base)
8. then install the cude toolkit from the extracted package (sudo sh cuda-linux64-rel-6.5.14-18749181.run)
9. after installation and setting the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH you sould be able to compile and run cuda samples.

---

a simple example you can find in cuda-samples/0_Simple/simplePrintf and compile it by running make command. Following was the output that I got:

GPU Device 0: "Quadro FX 5800" with compute capability 1.3

Device 0: "Quadro FX 5800" with Compute 1.3 capability
cuPrintf() is called. Output:

[1, 0]:     Value is:10
[1, 1]:     Value is:10
[1, 2]:     Value is:10
[1, 3]:     Value is:10
[1, 4]:     Value is:10
[1, 5]:     Value is:10
[1, 6]:     Value is:10
[1, 7]:     Value is:10
[3, 0]:     Value is:10
[3, 1]:     Value is:10
[3, 2]:     Value is:10
[3, 3]:     Value is:10
[3, 4]:     Value is:10
[3, 5]:     Value is:10
[3, 6]:     Value is:10
[3, 7]:     Value is:10
[2, 0]:     Value is:10
[2, 1]:     Value is:10
[2, 2]:     Value is:10
[2, 3]:     Value is:10
[2, 4]:     Value is:10
[2, 5]:     Value is:10
[2, 6]:     Value is:10
[2, 7]:     Value is:10
[0, 0]:     Value is:10
[0, 1]:     Value is:10
[0, 2]:     Value is:10
[0, 3]:     Value is:10
[0, 4]:     Value is:10
[0, 5]:     Value is:10
[0, 6]:     Value is:10
[0, 7]:     Value is:10